# What does 'drew her back into' mean in context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'drew her back into' mean in context? Can 'drew' be replaced with 'pulled'?

> He **drew her back into** himself again; again she was confronted with
>   the single eye, was pulled through the opening, oval pupil.

From *A Wind in the Door* by Madelene L'Engle.

Answer (score 1):

The word "drew" is of course the past tense of "draw", as "pulled" is of "pull".

The word "Draw" has quite a few meanings as a verb (and yet others as other parts of speech) as seen in [this definition from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/draw) (and there are other meanings I can think of not listed in this entry)

In this sense the literal meaning of sense 1 from the linked definition

> to cause to move continuously toward or after a force applied in advance : pull

or the figurative meaning of sense 3

> to bring by inducement or allure : attract

"Pull" has sufficiently [similar meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull)  that it could easily be substituted here, the choice is one of style.

Comment: You wrote 'the choice is one of style'. I would like to feel different in the style acording to what we use 'draw' or 'pull'.  Or it is impossible for not a native speaker?

Comment: @Vitaly  I don't understand what you mean by "feel different in the style". I meant that whether to use "pull" or "draw" is a stylistic choice, not affecting the meaning significantly. The rest of the sentence need not change based on this choice.

Comment: I mean it is difficult for me to feel the difference: Clock out, pull the curtains, and sleep. Lock the door, and draw the curtains, etc. All the time I am not sure what word to use 'draw' or 'pull' in any new my phrase which I did not see before.

Comment: I really don't get why people do not upvote these kinds of answers.